# Create directories and download files by reading input from a file

Tags: linux, unix, wget

```
cat paste_output.txt | while read -r file_name path_name file; 
do mkdir -p -- "$path_name"; 
wget "$file_name"; 
mv "$file" "$path_name"; 
done;
```

Hi! I have this piece of code that reads field by field from the file specified. What I am trying to do here is I am creating a directory that is specified in second field and then I am downloading file specified in first field and then after having that file downloaded I am that file in the directory specified in second field.

Output: I am getting the desired directory structure and files downloaded however files are downloading in the directory I am executing the commands from.

How to move files in the desired directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-P` flag of `wget` to put the file in the target directory.
If the directory doesn't exist, it will create it,
so this also let's you save on the `mkdir`.

```
while read -r file_name path_name file; do
    wget -P "$path_name" "$file_name"
done < paste_output.txt
```

I made some other improvements to the script:

- The `cat` is useless, input redirection is better
- The semicolons at end of lines are unnecessary
- It's good to indent the body of loops, for readability